# Finishing a problem using equalities

Tags: problem-solving, computational-mathematics

This is my problem:

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive real numbers with $abc=1$. Prove that
>   $$\frac{a^{n+2}}{a^n + (n-1)\,b^n} + \frac{b^{n+2}}{b^n + (n-1)\,c^n} + \frac{c^{n+2}}{c^n + (n-1)\,a^n} \geq \frac{3}{n}$$
>   for each integer $n$.

I used the Cauchy inequality but this is the closest I got:
$$\frac{a^{2n}}{a^n + (n-1)\,b^n} + \frac{b^{2n}}{b^n + (n-1)\,c^n} + \frac{c^{2n}}{c^n + (n-1)\,a^n} \geq \frac{3}{n}$$
I get the same with Jensen’s inequality. If I can show it for $2n$, how do I show it for $n+2$?

Comment: Have you considered beginning with n =1 and trying an induction arguement? That's what I'd try.

Comment: If $a = b = c = 1$, then the inequality becomes $\dfrac{3}{n} \ge \dfrac{3}{2}$ which is false for $n \ge 3$.

Comment: Ok,good point by Jimmy K,I hadn't thought of that. So basially he's saying that easy case doesn't work,so a b and c can't all be equal to 1 and that has to be added to the problem statement.I'm too tired, I'm going to bed and gonna try with a fresh head. If anyone beats me to it, ah well. I really DO think induction will be an essential part of any working proof. Sigh. Life without coffee is hard...........

Comment: I am sorry, it should 3/n. not 3/2

Comment: @JimmyK4542  In fact, since abc = 1, then at most one of the three values can be equal to 1: Assume 2 of the 3 numbers equals 1. Then this forces the third to the one since abc =1!